# "There are no scenes inside that module" -manim

Tags: python, manim

I am new to manim. I have been rendering a few examples of basic shapes and it has been working fine. Today the same code throws me the "There are no scenes inside that module" error. What might the problem be?

Heres is code to make a square that has been working just fine.

```
from manim import *

class SquareMaking(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        square = Square(side_length=2, color=BLUE)
        self.play(Create(square))
        self.wait(1)

        # Change Start and End Angles (Creating an arc)
        square.set_start_angle(-PI/4)
        square.set_end_angle(PI/2)
        self.wait(1)
```

Comment: it is good practice, for clarity, to avoid wildcard imports:
[wildcard imports](https://youtu.be/EueSSAyO3K0) pollute the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

It's also answered [here](https://github.com/ManimCommunity/manim/issues/1287#issuecomment-815592833).

I basically ran into the same problem where in Windows PS I simply typed: manim -pql Scene_name and it would perform its magic and display video.

I later decided to pip install manimlib to use the function: TexText (previously TexMobject). This results in the error you describe.

Incidentally, manimlib also has a command-line version of manim. So, now when "manim arga argb" is typed in PS it's being called from the manimlib vs manim package.